# When is $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})_R$ self-dual?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and consider the constant $R$-group scheme $G = (\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})_R$. I know that the Cartier dual of $G$ is the corresponding diagonalizable group scheme over $R$, and is therefore isomorphic to $\mu_{n, R}$. Is there a concrete way in terms of $n$ and $R$ to determine whether $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})_R \cong \mu_{n, R}$ as group schemes? When $R$ is a field it isn't too hard to work out (e.g. [What is difference between constant group scheme associated with cyclic group and $\mu_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797453/what-is-difference-between-constant-group-scheme-associated-with-cyclic-group-an)), but for general rings it seems a little bit more complicated, for instance because the group of $R$-points of $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})_R$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ unless $\mathrm{Spec} R$ is connected. And in this general setting one no longer has access to the Galois theory (or at least factorization of polynomials) available over fields.

I don't think that the answer can be that it is true if and only if $R$ has a primitive $n$-th root of unity (see the comments).

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for ? $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})_R\simeq \mu_{n,R}$ iff there is an isomorphism $f:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})_R\to \mu_{n,R}$ which happen iff $\mu_{n,R}$ has a global section, which happen iff $R$ contains a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Comment: @Roland sorry, I'm not sure why this works. For example, if $R = \mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$, then $R$ contains a primitive $2$nd root of unity, namely $-1$ [and in fact $X^2 - 1 = (X - 1)(X + 1)$ ]. But $R[X]/(X^2 - 1)$ isn't even isomorphic to $R \times R$ as an $R$-algebra (for instance because the first guy doesn't have enough idempotents). Maybe you can explain your argument a little bit more or why my counterexample is incorrect?

Comment: You are right, there is a problem in my previous comment. (two actually, one which can be easily corrected : $\mu_{n,R}$ should have a global section which span all others). The other, on contrary, is critical. The implication "if there is an isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})_R\to\mu_{n,R}$  then $\mu_{n,R}$ has a global section which span all others" holds, but not always its converse. Now I think that if $n$ is invertible in $R$, then what I said holds. If $n$ is not invertible in $R$, then the two group schemes are never self dual.

Comment: @Roland what about when $R$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0? In that case you do have an isomorphism, despite $n$ not being invertible in $R$, right?

Comment: Yes but this is what I said, if $n$ is invertible in $R$, then you have the isomorphism iff $R$ contains a primitive root of unity. So if $R$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, then $R$ has a primitive root of unity and the two groups are isomorphic. If $n$ is not invertible, you never have the isomorphism (because you can pull back to an separably closed field of characteristic $p|n$ and then you will have nilpotent in $\mu_{n,R}$ and not in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I see, my bad - I got the implication reversed. So if $n$ is invertible, why does the existence of such an isomorphism imply the existence of a generating global section? In particular, doesn't $\mu_n$ have ring of global sections $R[T]/(T^n - 1)$ which is always generated by a single element $T$? Since taking global sections is contravariant, did you mean that $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ has a generating global section?

Comment: i.e. a collection of $n$ distinct $n$-th roots of unity in $R$, one for each coordinate in $R \times \cdots \times R$. So this certainly implies that $R$ has $n$ distinct roots of unity (but maybe not that $T^n - 1$ splits over $R$?). Is this what you mean? How do you continue from here by using the assumption that $n$ is invertible in $R$?

Comment: By global section, I meant a global section of the sheaf (on $Sch/\operatorname{Spec}R$) represented by $\mu_{n,R}$.